# Объединение двух массивов c объектами

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

У меня есть два массива с объектами.

```
const array1 = [
   {
      id: 1,
   },
   {
      id: 2,
   },
   {
      id: 3,
   },
];
```

и

```
const array2 = [
   {
       name: 'Вася',
       phone: +7123456789,
   },
   {
       name: 'Саша',
       phone: +7987654321,
   },
   {
       name: 'Таня',
       phone: +7569874232,
   },
];
```

Я хочу получить массив объектов на основе двух моих массивов объектов.

```
const array3 = [
   {
       id: 1,
       name: 'Вася',
       phone: +7123456789,
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       name: 'Саша',
       phone: +7987654321,
   },
   {
       id: 3,
       name: 'Таня',
       phone: +7569874232,
   },
];
```

Как можно объединить два массива?

Так же я пробовал пройти по двум массивам в одном цикле, но не получилось.

```
for (const [id, details] of [array1, array2]) {
    //  Тут выполняю действия с id и details
}
```

Но я пришел к выводу что лучше объединить два массива, чем нежели использовать например два цикла `for`.

Comment: @MaximLensky боюсь вы не поняли мою проблему. У меня нет `array3` я хочу его получить, а не просто склеить два массива

Comment: а точно ..не дошло до меня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так, `spread` пригодится для склеивания объектов

```js
const array1 = [{
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
  },
];
const array2 = [{
    name: 'Вася',
    phone: +7123456789,
  },
  {
    name: 'Саша',
    phone: +7987654321,
  },
  {
    name: 'Таня',
    phone: +7569874232,
  },
];
const array3 = array1.map((item, index) =>
  ({
    ...item,
    ...array2[index],
  })
);

console.log(array3)
```